# Github Action trigger on another repo update (push, pull_request)

Tags: github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm having some trouble setting up a proper build chain for me and some friends.
So, I forked two repos, the official ghidra and ghidra-ci.
ghidra-ci is an repo which builds your fork of ghidra, when you cherry-pick some pr's so, you can add some things which aren't added to the official ghidra repo yet.

So, ghidra-ci should build the ghidra repo when the ghidra repo is updated.
So far I managed to get it to build when ghidra-ci itself is updatet. I used

```
name: Ghidra Build
on: [push, pull_request]
```

(After this are only the build jobs)

So, I know this is wrong.
I deleted the `on:`  line, but I it wants a `on:`  line, I just pasted `on: [workflow_dispatch]` in. I don't know if this is gonna work.

I have a workflow called "Check for new commits"

```
name: Check for new commits
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '30 12 * * *'
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs: {}

jobs:
  # Ensure all steps use a common revision
  check:
    name: Check for new commits since last release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          repository: Lockna/Ghidra
      - name: Check for new commits
        id: check
        run: |
          LAST_REL_NAME=$(curl --silent "https://api.github.com/repos/${{github.repository}}/releases/latest" | jq .name)
          LAST_REL_COMMITID=$(echo $LAST_REL_NAME | grep -oP "\(\K\w+(?=\))")
          COMMIT_HASH_SHORT=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)
          COMMIT_HASH_LONG=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
          echo "Latest commit is $COMMIT_HASH_LONG"
          if [[ "$LAST_REL_NAME" == *"$COMMIT_HASH_SHORT"* ]]; then
            echo "No commits since last release $LAST_REL_NAME"
          else
            echo "Found new commits since $LAST_REL_NAME. Triggering ci."
            echo ::set-output name=trigger::true
            echo ::set-output name=rev::$COMMIT_HASH_LONG
            echo ::set-output name=lastrev::$LAST_REL_COMMITID
          fi
      - name: Trigger build
        if: steps.check.outputs.trigger
        uses: benc-uk/workflow-dispatch@v1.1
        with:
          workflow: "Ghidra Build"
          repo: Lockna/ghidra-ci
          token: ${{secrets.PAT_TOKEN}}
          inputs: '{ "rev": "${{steps.check.outputs.rev}}", "prevRev": "${{steps.check.outputs.lastrev}}" }'
```

so, this workflow should check (I would prefer that it triggers when I'm updating the ghidra itself, but I have found out that this doesn't work out as I would like to) if there are some changes and if there are some it should trigger the "Ghidra Build" workflow. For testing I run this build manually

```
Run benc-uk/workflow-dispatch@v1.1
  with:
    workflow: Ghidra Build
    repo: Lockna/ghidra-ci
    token: ***
    inputs: { "rev": "c1a1674214007bf467dd90f6d80fda453d25b16c", "prevRev": "133d6c2" }
Workflow id is: 3932827
Error: Unexpected inputs provided
```

That's the error message I get.
I don't know what else I could try to get this work.
If someone has a solution where it really builds when ghidra repo is updated, I would like to hear that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could have ghidra-ci listen to the [`repository_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#repository_dispatch) event:

```yaml
name: Listener for ghidra

on:
  repository_dispatch:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  dump:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Dump event payload
        run: |
          jq . "$GITHUB_EVENT_PATH"
```

`workflow_dispatch` is there so you can manually trigger the workflow for test purposes. The `run` step just dumps the event payload, and you can replace that with whatever build steps you want; you can further filter which events should trigger by filtering by event type, such as

```yaml
on:
  repository_dispatch:
    types:
      - mytrigger
```

In ghidra, you can [generate that event](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/repos#create-a-repository-dispatch-event) by sending a POST request to `/repos/Lockna/ghidra-ci/dispatches`, for example using the [GitHub CLI](https://github.com/cli/cli):

```yaml
name: Notify ghidra-ci

on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  notify:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Create repository dispatch event
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT_TOKEN }}
        run: |
          gh api repos/Lockna/ghidra-ci/dispatches \
              --raw-field event_type=mytrigger
```

Again, the `workflow_dispatch` trigger is there to allow manual triggering.

For authentication, you must use a personal access token with at least `public_repo` scope; `$GITHUB_TOKEN` alone doesn't work.

The value set for `event_type` shows up as `action` in the event payload.